# How can I change the directory of a document with gdrive?

Tags: command-line, drive, google

Which command allows me to directly change the directory of a file on Google Drive using [gdrive](https://github.com/prasmussen/gdrive) command.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `gdrive update` command available, but I am not able to use it:

```
[root@computer][~]# gdriveupdate -p <DIRECTORY ID> myfile.docx  
Uploading myfile.docx
Failed to upload file: googleapi: Error 403: The parents field is not directly writable in update requests. Use the addParents and removeParents parameters instead., fieldNotWritable
```

So I was forced to create bash functions that would

Download the file
Delete the online file that is in the wrong directory
Upload the file at the right location

I had to make the distinction between

Google document files that require commands export and import
Non Google document files where the commands download and upload can be used

Importing documents and exporting them again with .docx extension is better than .odt extension (e.g equation are in image with .odt whereas they are editable after exporting the document with .docx extension).

I have created a folder `$HOME/.gdrive/files` to store the downloaded file.

The two functions are

1. `gdrive-change-dir-doc <FILE ID> <DESTINATION FOLDER ID>`

   ```
   gdrive-change-dir-doc () {
   cd /root/.gdrive/files
   rm -i *
   gdrive export --mime application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document $1
   gdrive delete $1
   gdrive import -p $2 *
   }
   ```
2. `gdrive-change-dir-non-doc <FILE ID> <DESTINATION FOLDER ID>`

   ```
   gdrive-change-dir-non-doc () {
   cd /root/.gdrive/files
   rm -i *
   gdrive download $1
   gdrive upload -p $2 *
   gdrive delete $1
   }
   ```

You can now create powerful command such as putting all unsorted docs in one online folder:

```
[root@computer][~]# drive list --absolute | grep -v "/" | grep doc| awk '{ print $1 }'|while read i
do
       gdrive-change-dir-doc $i <DESTINATION FOLDER>
Done
```